# How to change the background colour of a web page

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I am not sure on how to change the background colour of a web page. I have been researching for an answer and they have been pointing at the bootstrap.css which is understandable, however, I do not know how to assign these to a specific web form.

This is an example of the code I have placed into bootstrap.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#183adb;

}
```

This is my web page, markup code

```
<%@ Page Title="AddProject" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddProject.aspx.cs" Inherits="help.AddProject" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div class="Jumbotron">
        <h1>CREATE A NEW PROJECT:</h1>
    </div>
     <div class ="Container-fluid"> 
          <br />

        <div class ="Row">         
            <asp:Label ID="lblprojectName" runat="server" Text="Project Name"></asp:Label>  
        </div>

        <div class ="Row">      
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectName2" runat="server" Width="517px" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
          <br />
    <div class ="Row">                 
            <asp:Label ID="lblProjectDesc" runat="server" Text="Project Description"></asp:Label>           
        </div>
        <div class ="Row">              
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectDesc" runat="server" Height="52px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="521px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>                  
        </div>
          <br />

    <div class ="Row">
            <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>      
            </div>

        <div class ="Row">                   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Width="164px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>  &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnChangeDate" runat="server" Text="Change" OnClick="btnChangeDate_Click" />
            </div>
          <asp:Calendar ID="calStartDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="calStartDate_SelectionChanged" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
          <br />

           <div class ="Row">
            <asp:Label ID="lblFinishDate" runat="server" Text="Finish Date"></asp:Label>      
            </div>

        <div class ="Row">                   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinishDate" runat="server" Width="164px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnChangeDate2" runat="server" Text="Change" OnClick="btnChangeDate2_Click" />                 
            </div>
         <asp:Calendar ID="CalFinishDate" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="CalFinishDate_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
         </div>


    <div class = "Container-fluid">
        <br />
        <div class ="Row">
            <asp:Button ID="btnCreateProject" runat="server" Text="Save & Add" Height="40px" Width="94px" OnClick="btnCreateProject_Click" />
             <asp:Button ID="btnClearProject" runat="server" Text="Clear all" Height="40px" Width="94px" OnClick="BtnClearProject_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I think I meant to say web page, sorry

Comment: where is the body and html form..

Comment: Do you mean the bootstrap or site form, that code up there is my web page hahaha I'm so sorry I am very new to ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the CSS code directly in your Site.Master page inside the `<head></head>` tag, not in bootstrap.css:

```
<style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #183adb;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought it had to been in the bootstrap that's why I was confused! I understand it now :)

Comment: No, you should not modify the bootstrap files, because every time you have to upgrade bootstrap, it will overwrite the files and all your changes will be lost.

Comment: Okay, I am new to ASP and always assumed that all the design code had to be done through bootstrap for some reason.  Well everything has clicked now, thank you :)